# kubectl patch existing container command

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have a Kubernetes deployment up and running:
(some fields omitted for brevity)

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: argocd-server
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: argocd-server
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: argocd-server
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: argocd-server
          image: quay.io/argoproj/argocd:v2.2.5
          command:
            - argocd-server
```

I would like to create a patch for the existing deployment to add certain arguements to the `command` of the container:

```
            - '--insecure'
            - '--basehref'
            - /argocd
```

I read the documentation on the `kubectl patch` command [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/), but I am not sure how to actually select the container (by name or index) that I would like to patch.
It would be fine to overwrite the complete `command:` list (giving the `- argocd-server` line in the patch file) but I would like to prevent giving the complete `containers:` spec in the patch file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the container by index, e.g.:

```sh
kubectl patch deployment argocd-server -n argocd --type='json' -p='[{"op": "replace", "path": "/spec/template/spec/containers/0/command", "value": ["argocd-server", "--insecure"]}]'
```

Comment: The patch JSON is invalid, because it is referencing `command` in the path, yet specifies an object with the field `command` as replacement value.
Here is the corrected version:
`kubectl patch deployment argocd-server -n argocd --type='json' -p='[{"op": "replace", "path": "/spec/template/spec/containers/0/command", "value": ["argocd-server", "--insecure"]}]'`

Comment: Yep, I was a bit too quick. I'll update the command

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the inspiration by @Blokje5 I was able to construct these two options:

### JSON approach

#### inline

```
kubectl patch deployment argocd-server -n argocd --type='json' -p='[{"op": "replace", "path": "/spec/template/spec/containers/0/command", "value": ["argocd-server", "--insecure", "--basehref", "/argocd"]}]'
```

#### with patch file

`patch.json`

```
[
  {
    "op": "replace",
    "path": "/spec/template/spec/containers/0/command",
    "value": [
      "argocd-server",
      "--insecure",
      "--basehref",
      "/argocd"
    ]
  }
]
```

```
kubectl -n argocd patch deployment argocd-server --type='json' --patch-file patch.json
```

### YAML approach

#### yaml file

`patch.yaml`

```
---
op: replace
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: argocd-server
          command:
            - argocd-server
            - --insecure
            - --basehref
            - /argocd
```

```
kubectl -n argocd patch deployment argocd-server --patch-file patch.yaml
```